# panning/dragging issue in highmap clicking on Russia from worldview

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

**Expected behaviour**

Clicking on Russia disables the vertical dragging/panning.

**Actual behaviour**

I am trying to use highchart API with maps plugin. I have just noticed that clicking from worldmap view on Russia country will zoom to the country but it disables the vertical dragging/panning.

**Live demo with steps to reproduce**

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/aaLuxgg6/2/][1]
```

Comment: Looks like a bug - reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6287) - it works in Highmaps 5.0.5 - see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaLuxgg6/15/)

Comment: It is asked by me. Thanks for the information.